# I would like to make my menu bar scroll with the page

Tags: html, css

I would like to make my menu bar scroll with the page. Can someone help me with this?
I dont know what to try because i am new in this.
I also have another question: i would like to disable the scrolling function in my home page.
I tried to use overflow: hidden but that didn't work.

my html code is:

```
<center>
<img  src="logo.jpg" alt="logo" width=900 height=500 id="logo"/> 
</center>


<div> <table id="navigatie-venster"> 
    <tr>
        <td> <a href=index.html>Startpagina</a> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> <a href=bestuur.html>Bestuur</a> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> <a href=trainers.html>Trainers</a> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> <a href=disciplines.html>Disciplines</a> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> <a href=waartrainenwij.html>Waar trainen wij</a> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> <a href=uurrooster.html>Uurrooster</a> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> <a href=contact.html>Contact</a> </td>
    </tr>

</table> </div>

<div> <table id="navigatie-vensterr"> 
    <tr>
        <td> <a href=index.html>Startpagina</a> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> <a href=bestuur.html>Bestuur</a> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> <a href=trainers.html>Trainers</a> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> <a href=disciplines.html>Disciplines</a> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> <a href=waartrainenwij.html>Waar trainen wij</a> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> <a href=uurrooster.html>Uurrooster</a> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> <a href=contact.html>Contact</a> </td>
    </tr>

</table> </div>

<div id="facebook">
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/KoninklijkeTurnkringAalst"  target="_blank" > <img  src="facebook.jpg" alt="facebook" width=100 height=100 >  </a> 
</div>

<div id="kwaliteitslabel">
<img  src="kwaliteitslabel.jpg" alt="kwaliteitslabel" width=100 height=100 /> 
</div>

</body>
```

my css is:

```
body{ background: rgba(169,3,41,1);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(169,3,41,1) 0%, rgba(143,2,34,1) 44%, rgba(109,0,25,1) 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(left top, right top, color-stop(0%, rgba(169,3,41,1)), color-stop(44%, rgba(143,2,34,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(109,0,25,1)));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(169,3,41,1) 0%, rgba(143,2,34,1) 44%, rgba(109,0,25,1) 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(169,3,41,1) 0%, rgba(143,2,34,1) 44%, rgba(109,0,25,1) 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(169,3,41,1) 0%, rgba(143,2,34,1) 44%, rgba(109,0,25,1) 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(169,3,41,1) 0%, rgba(143,2,34,1) 44%, rgba(109,0,25,1) 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#a90329', endColorstr='#6d0019', GradientType=1 );}

#navigatie-venster {position: absolute;
left: 0px; top: 150px; }    

#navigatie-vensterr{ position: absolute;
right: 0px; top: 150px; direction: rtl; }
```

Comment: P.S: `<center>` tag is deprecated.

Comment: This is all we can see from the code you've posted: http://jsbin.com/hujaqe/1/edit?html,css,output Believe me, makes hard to even imagine what you're after.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan: `center` tag is no longer `deprecated`. It is now `obsolete` and `non-conforming`: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html#obsolete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dude check this code Here

http://jsfiddle.net/naveenkumarpg/bepnus8u/

Hope this is what you are expecting

```
<div id="fixedheader">
    <img src="logo.jpg" alt="logo" width=900 height=500 id="logo" />
</div>
```

i have modified your header with the div
and updated css as well.

there are some problems in HTML as well i have fixed them.

CSS here :

```
#fixedheader {
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:100%;
    float:left: display:block;
    text-align:center;
    background:#fff;
}
```

Hope this is what you want.

Cheers

Comment: this does work!! but my pucture "logo" and background have changed

Comment: you just wanted to mention the height to the "fixedheader" like how much you want then you are good to go.

Comment: i just added :
position: fixed;
display:block;
And it works!! thx man